# Very slow speed of gcc compiled C-program under Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have two OS on my PC with i7-3770 @ 3.40 GHz. One OS is latest Linux Kubuntu 18.04, the other OS is Windows 10 Pro running on same HDD.

I have tested a simple funny program written in C language doing some arithmetic calculations from number theory. On Kubuntu compiled with gcc 7.3.0, on Windows compiled with gcc 5.2.0. built by MinGW-W64 project.

The result is amazing, running program was 4-times slower on Linux, than on Windows.

On Windows the elapsed time is just 6 seconds. On Linux is elapsed time 24 seconds! On the same hardware.

I tried on Kubuntu to compile with some CPU specific options like "gcc -corei7" etc., but nothing helped. In the program is used "math.h" library, so the compilation is done with "-lm" on both systems. The source code is the same.

Is there a reason for this slow speed under Linux?

Further more I have compiled the same code also on older 32-bit machine with Core Duo T2250 @ 1.73 GHz under Linux Mint 19 with gcc 7.3.0. The elapsed time was 28 seconds! Not much difference than 64-bit machine running on double frequency under Linux.

The sorce code is below, you can compile it and test it.

```
/* Program for playing with sigma(n) and tau(n) functions */
/* Compilation of code: "gcc name.c -o name -lm"             */ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
double i, nq, x, zacatek, konec, p;       
double odx, soucet, delitel, celkem, ZM;
unsigned long cas1, cas2;

i=(double)0; soucet=(double)0; celkem=(double)0; nq=(double)0;

zacatek=(double)1; konec=(double)1000000; x=zacatek;

ZM=(double)16 / (double)10;

printf("\n Program for playing with sigma(n) and tau(n) functions \n");
printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Calculation is running in range from %.0lf to %.0lf\n\n\n", zacatek, konec);
printf("Finding numbers which have sigma(n)/n = %.3lf\n\n", ZM);

cas1=time(NULL); 

 while (x <= konec) {
  i=1; celkem=0; nq=0;
  odx=sqrt(x)+1;
  while (i <= odx) {   
     if (fmod(x, i)==0) {
     nq++;
     celkem=celkem+x/i+i;
     }
   i++;
   }    
   nq=2*nq-1;
   if ((odx-floor(odx))==0) {celkem=celkem-odx;}
   if (fabs(celkem - (ZM*x)) < 0.001) {
      printf("%.0lf has sum of all divisors = %.3lf times the number itself (%.0lf, %.0lf)\n", x, ZM, celkem, nq+1);
      }
   x++;
 }

cas2=time(NULL);

printf("\n\nProgram ended.\n\n");
printf("Elapsed time %lu seconds.\n\n", cas2-cas1);

return (0);
}
```

Comment: what flags did you compile with?  Make sure you're compiling with -O3 on both setups.

Comment: *`Compilation of code: "gcc name.c -o name -lm"`* - Why didn't you enable optimizations? Try with `gcc -O2`.

Comment: *"I tried ... some ... options like `gcc -corei7` etc., but nothing helped"* Have you tried `-O3` (or any `-O_`)? `-march=native`? `-ffast-math`?

Comment: With `-O3`, I get 25 seconds on my system (Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.3, x86_64). With `-O3 -ffast-math` I get 3 seconds. (`-ffast-math` can break things.)

Comment: Thank you very much guys! This works "-O3 -ffast-math" perfect! I have 4 seconds now. Thats a big difference. I was not aware of this option. Thank you for your time!  You're good!

Comment: Still does not explain the speed _difference_ however.  How fast does it run on Win10 with the same options I wonder?

Comment: You should use appropriate types for your variables. `i`, `nq` and perhaps `x` and `konec` should be integers. Maybe some others as well. You are going on the edge when comparing these numbers while floating point.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Thank you for comments! I am just an amatuer free time programmer.

Comment: @Clifford Now with option "-O3 -ffast-math" is the speed exactly the same 4 seconds on both systems Linux and Windows. Strange thing is, that I have used on Windows the gcc command without any of these options. So it must be preset?

Comment: @ZdeněkČervenka: gcc is actually a frontend for a number of other programs, so it uses a [spec file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) that defines how those other programs are run.  You can run `gcc -dumpspecs` on different OSes and compare them (especially the `cc1` section for C compiler options), or `gcc -specs=FILE ...` to use a different spec file than the default installed.

Comment: Very good. Thank you very much for explanation!